# How to display values of database after page is loaded using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want  to dispaly monthwise records in table .for that i am using jquery.I am getting result when i change year from drop-down.But I also want my values related to year to be displayed after page loaded ,before changing

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //$("#form1").load(function(){
              //$("#year").on("change",function(){
                $("#year").change(function(){
                 var dataString = 'year='+ $(this).val();
                  $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "monthname.php",
                     dataType: 'json',
                   //  data: dataString,
                 // data: "{'dataString':'"+'months='+ $(this).val()+"','year_value':'"+'year='+ $('#year').val()+"'}",
                     data: dataString,
                     cache: false,
                     success: function (data) {
                        $('#jan').val(data.month_name1);  
                        $('#feb').val(data.month_name2); 
                        $('#march').val(data.month_name3); 
                        $('#april').val(data.month_name4); 
                        $('#may').val(data.month_name5); 
                        $('#june').val(data.month_name6); 
                        $('#july').val(data.month_name7); 
                        $('#august').val(data.month_name8); 
                        $('#september').val(data.month_name9); 
                        $('#october').val(data.month_name10); 
                        $('#november').val(data.month_name11); 
                        $('#december').val(data.month_name12); 

                  }
               });
             });
          });

        </script>
      </head>
      <form id="form1">
       <body>

         Select Year 
     <?php
          $year = 2015;
          $i=1;
            echo '<select name="year" id="year">';

         while($i<21)
         {
            echo '<option>'. $year.' </option>';
             $year++;
             $i++;
         }

         echo '</select>';
     ?>
      <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border: 1px solid black;">
         <!--tr>
             <td><label>Application</label></td><td><label>January</label></td><td><label>February</label></td><td>March</td><td>April</td><td>May</td><td>June</td>
             <td>July</td><td>August</td><td>September</td><td>October</td><td>November</td><td>December</td>        
         </tr-->
         <tr>
             <td>Form</td><td>January</td><td>February</td><td>March</td><td>April</td><td>May</td><td>June</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Employee </td><td><input type="text" name="jan" id="jan" readonly></td><td><input type="text" name="feb" id="feb" readonly></td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="march" id="march" readonly></td><td><input type="text" name="april" id="april" readonly></td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="may" id="may" readonly></td><td><input type="text" name="june" id="june" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Form</td><td>July</td><td>August</td><td>September</td><td>October</td><td>November</td><td>December</td>
          </tr>

           <tr>
                    <td>Employee </td><td><input type="text" name="july" id="july" readonly></td><td><input type="text" name="august" id="august" readonly></td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="september" id="september" readonly></td><td><input type="text" name="october" id="october" readonly></td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="november" id="november" readonly></td><td><input type="text" name="december" id="december" readonly></td>
          </tr>
      </table></form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of the select and then trigger change event which will run the ajax you have shown

```
var currYear = new Date().getFullYear();

$("#year").change(function(){
    // your existing ajax code

}).val(currYear).change();
```